# Graph Clustering based on the edge weights

Tags: python, graph, cluster-analysis, networkx

I have built a graph using networkx which is a social network with people as nodes and the messaging frequencies as the edge weights. I want to cluster this network into different groups of people. The ones who message each other a lot tend to be in the same group. How do I go about this? Which clustering algorithm should I use? Also, how do I visualize the grouping like a dendrogram tree?

Thanks in advance! :D
P.S.: I have tried python-louvain for partitioning but that gives inaccurate results like it partitioned two users into different groups even when their messaging frequency was pretty high

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried python-louvain for partitioning but that gives inaccurate results[...]

The Louvain method is not perfect and there are no perfect methods, they always depend on what you are trying to achieve (see conclusion of [this paper](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01976587/document)).

> [...] like it partitioned two users into different groups even when their messaging frequency was pretty high.

It seems that this user may belong to more than a single community... Maybe try a partitioning method that allows overlapping communities, such as [K-Clique](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.community.kclique.k_clique_communities.html#networkx.algorithms.community.kclique.k_clique_communities). This kind of partitioning methods allow nodes to belong to more than a single community.

#### Algorithms:

Here are some alternative algorithms that I’ve found:

1. There are a number of algorithms already included in the networkX package([here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/community.html)). I would suggest `girvan_newman`but it takes a lot of computation power...
2. The CDLib package also has a number of algorithms for networkX([here](https://cdlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/cd_algorithms/node_clustering.html)), including some that allow for overlapping communities. Also, check the [leiden algorithm](https://cdlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/cd_algorithms/algs/cdlib.algorithms.leiden.html#cdlib.algorithms.leiden), you may prefer it to louvain, it's supposed to be better(according to their [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.08473.pdf))
3. I would still recommend using [python-louvain](https://python-louvain.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html), for crisp communities

Good luck!

Comment: Edited my answer, see if it helped!